# XAF: How to minimize ribbon from code in XAF Windows App

Tags: devexpress, ribbon, xaf

I want to minimize the ribbon when user click on particular navigation Item.
For example - when User clicks on Dashboard nav item, I want the ribbon minimized, and automatically "maximized" on others.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Please consider to elaborate about your answer, so that it may help others in future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that I can simple access the ribbon in the `ViewController`.
So like usual in XAF, override "`OnActivated`" and do the magic there

```
    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        if (Frame.Template != null)
        {
            ((XtraFormTemplateBase)Frame.Template)).RibbonTransformer.Ribbon
                                           .Minimized = View.Id == "TestView;
        }
        base.OnActivated();
    }
```

I got a couple of errors while accessing `Frame.Template` being `NULL` when I'd hit a dashboardview, with many nested ListView in it. Make sure You don't forget to check it :)

Answer (score 0):

They released a hotfix for this bug in Devexpress's version 22.1.4. Today I updated to 22.1.4 while getting this error when there was version 22.1.3 and the error was completely resolved.

[NullReferenceException is thrown in the MinimizedRibbonPopupForm.GetSizeWithIndents method when the Classic panel style is used](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/T1097518/nullreferenceexception-is-thrown-in-the-minimizedribbonpopupform-getsizewithindents)